# Config version check in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm revamping an apache-php application. The main goal is to make it easily portable between hosts. I moved every path-dependent setting from .htaccess files to the virtualhost specification, but it would be nice being able to match the **version** of the config file to the version of the site.

What I thought of is two constants defined in the vhost config (as environment variables). Like:

- `lowVersion` containing the lowest version of the application this config file is compatible with.
- `highVersion` containing the version of the app when the last config file change happened.

So the application's central `.htaccess` file could check if:

- if `lowVersion` is not bigger than the version of the application and
- if `highVersion` is not lower than the minimum config version needed by the app.

I know about SetEnv, SetEnvIf and Rewrite, but they don't seem to support comparing numbers in a greater-than and less-than fasshion.

Of course I could use a special number system like:

- 3 = iii
- 4 = iiii
- etc

... and use RegEx to compare them (if one contains the other than it is greater), but there must be some more... prosfessional solution. :)

Comment: mod_rewrite CAN do a comparison like `id > 1234`. I just still do not understand how are you going to use it...

Comment: @LazyOne AFAIK mod_rewrite has only things like *lexicographically precedes*, which won't work with numbers.

Comment: It does -- it's a simple string comparison, and will work fine for positive integer numbers. I did answered one question here where such comparison was involved and it is working fine. It was over a month ago ... and I'm too lazy to search for it now ...

Comment: **Task:** There are pages like `/198655.html`. Need to execute 301 redirect for all pages that have numbers between 152600 and 153655 to `/us/` subfolder and all other into `/en/` subfolder. **Code:** http://pastebin.com/Jp7n8mdp . YOU CAN do number comparison -- it is not perfect and number has to be formatted accordingly .. but it is possible in simple cases. If you can make your numbers simple (e.g. comparing `04 < 11` and not `4 < 11`) then it may work for you.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, zero padding really solves it. Please post it as an aswer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache's **mod_rewrite** can do a comparison like `id > 1234` -- it will be done as string comparison though (*lexicographically precedes* and *lexicographically follows*).

**Real-Life Example**

**Task:** There are pages like `/198655.html`. Need to execute 301 redirect for all pages that have numbers between 152600 and 153655 to `/us/` subfolder and all other into `/en/` subfolder.

**Code:** http://pastebin.com/Jp7n8mdp

```
RewriteCond $1 >152600
RewriteCond $1 <153655
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/us/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/en/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

YOU CAN do number comparison -- it is not perfect and number has to be formatted accordingly .. but it is possible in simple cases. If you can make your numbers simple (e.g. comparing `04 < 11` and not `4 < 11`) then it may work for you.